# Postgres recovery mode deleted data after crash?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, recovery

Postgres was killed by the OOM killer after another process consumed too much memory. Postgres restarted and came back up fine, but somehow deleted over 2 years of data that were stored in the database, and I'm trying to figure out how.

What would cause Postgres to delete data like this? It was in recovery mode for a brief time, and seemed to have resolved itself, but somehow ended up deleting hundreds of GB of data without so much as a log. The schema was recovered, but no data since the crash exists in the database, and there are no files older than the crash in the `postgresql/9.5/main/base` directory for this database.

```
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [27442-2] LOG:  server process (PID 10522) was terminated by signal 11: Segmentation fault
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [27442-3] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10500-3] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10500-4] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10500-5] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10479-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10479-2] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10479-3] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10480-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10480-2] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10480-3] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10550-1] postgres@get_primed WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10550-2] postgres@get_primed DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10550-3] postgres@get_primed HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10492-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10492-2] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10492-3] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10512-1] postgres@get_primed WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10512-2] postgres@get_primed DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10512-3] postgres@get_primed HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10508-3] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10508-4] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10508-5] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10515-3] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10515-4] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10515-5] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [27447-2] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [27447-3] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [27447-4] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10491-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10491-2] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10491-3] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [25174-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [25174-2] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [25174-3] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10490-3] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10490-4] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10490-5] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [27442-4] LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10629-1] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2021-10-11 13:30:32 MDT
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10630-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10629-2] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10632-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10631-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10633-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10634-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10635-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10636-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10637-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10638-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:47 MDT [10639-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:48 MDT [10640-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:48 MDT [10641-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:48 MDT [10643-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:48 MDT [10642-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:48 MDT [10644-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:48 MDT [10645-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:48 MDT [10646-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:48 MDT [10647-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:48 MDT [10648-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:48 MDT [10649-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:48 MDT [10650-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:48 MDT [10651-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:48 MDT [10652-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:48 MDT [10653-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:48 MDT [10654-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:48 MDT [10655-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:48 MDT [10656-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:48 MDT [10658-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:48 MDT [10659-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:48 MDT [10657-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:48 MDT [10660-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:49 MDT [10666-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:49 MDT [10661-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:49 MDT [10663-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:49 MDT [10662-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:49 MDT [10664-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:49 MDT [10667-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:49 MDT [10668-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:49 MDT [10669-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:49 MDT [10670-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:49 MDT [10671-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:49 MDT [10629-3] LOG:  redo starts at 77B/2A7BAC8
2021-10-11 13:36:49 MDT [10672-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:49 MDT [10673-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:49 MDT [10629-4] LOG:  invalid record length at 77B/4760208
2021-10-11 13:36:49 MDT [10629-5] LOG:  redo done at 77B/47601E0
2021-10-11 13:36:49 MDT [10629-6] LOG:  last completed transaction was at log time 2021-10-11 13:36:47.515804-06
2021-10-11 13:36:49 MDT [10674-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:49 MDT [10629-7] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2021-10-11 13:36:49 MDT [27442-5] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2021-10-11 13:36:49 MDT [10681-1] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2021-10-11 13:36:49 MDT [10676-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:49 MDT [10677-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 13:36:49 MDT [10675-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2021-10-11 15:02:09 MDT [12635-1] postgres@tls_clienthellos13 LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Can't happen, unless you are using unsafe settings, bad hardware or run into a PostgreSQL bug. To guess which it is, we need to know your configuration.

Comment: That sounds quite unlikely that the crash killed a specific time range of data. The logfile also states that  the last committed transaction was from 2021-10-11 13:36:47 so that's definitely not 2 years ago. If I had to guess: the data was already deleted before the crash but nobody noticed. You only checked it _because_ of the crash. And besides: Postgres 9.5 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Were you using any unlogged tables?  As the documentation states, those would be truncated in a crash.

Comment: I've never seen the OOM killer using sig 11.  It uses sig 9.

Comment: @Jeremy thanks, that appears to be the issue here. Was not aware of that option (or its consequence), but good to know!